“Bus Error and Resource Tracker Warning When Training PyTorch Model on GPU with MPS”
I’ve built a vanilla Transformer using PyTorch for machine translation and am encountering issues while trying to train it on an Apple Mac M3 with a 12-core CPU and an 18-core GPU (18GB RAM) environment. Below are the details and issues I’m facing:
1.Device Selection Issue:
I’m setting up the device with the following code:
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "mps" if torch.has_mps or torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"
print("Using device:", device)

Although MPS is detected and selected, training crashes immediately after starting, with the following error:
/opt/anaconda3/envs/mynewenv/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d ').

2.CPU Training:
When I switch to CPU training on the same machine, it runs without any issues using the same batch size of 8.
3.Google Colab Training:
There are no issues when running the same code on Google Colab.
I’m looking for insights into what might be causing these issues on MPS and how I could resolve them. Specifically, I’d like to understand the semaphore leak and bus error that seems to occur only when using MPS. If needed, I can provide specific code snippets or further details.
from model import build_transformer
from dataset import BilingualDataset, causal_mask
from config import get_config, get_weights_file_path

import torchtext.datasets as datasets
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import LambdaLR

import warnings
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Huggingface datasets and tokenizers
from datasets import load_dataset
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import WordLevel
from tokenizers.trainers import WordLevelTrainer
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Whitespace

import wandb

import torchmetrics

def greedy_decode(model, source, source_mask, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, max_len, device):
    sos_idx = tokenizer_tgt.token_to_id('[SOS]')
    eos_idx = tokenizer_tgt.token_to_id('[EOS]')

    # Precompute the encoder output and reuse it for every step
    encoder_output = model.encode(source, source_mask)
    # Initialize the decoder input with the sos token
    decoder_input = torch.empty(1, 1).fill_(sos_idx).type_as(source).to(device)
    while True:
        if decoder_input.size(1) == max_len:
            break

        # build mask for target
        decoder_mask = causal_mask(decoder_input.size(1)).type_as(source_mask).to(device)

        # calculate output
        out = model.decode(encoder_output, source_mask, decoder_input, decoder_mask)

        # get next token
        prob = model.project(out[:, -1])
        _, next_word = torch.max(prob, dim=1)
        decoder_input = torch.cat(
            [decoder_input, torch.empty(1, 1).type_as(source).fill_(next_word.item()).to(device)], dim=1
        )

        if next_word == eos_idx:
            break

    return decoder_input.squeeze(0)


def run_validation(model, validation_ds, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, max_len, device, print_msg, global_step, num_examples=2):
    model.eval()
    count = 0

    source_texts = []
    expected = []
    predicted = []

    try:
        # get the console window width
        with os.popen('stty size', 'r') as console:
            _, console_width = console.read().split()
            console_width = int(console_width)
    except:
        # If we can't get the console width, use 80 as default
        console_width = 80

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in validation_ds:
            count += 1
            encoder_input = batch["encoder_input"].to(device) # (b, seq_len)
            encoder_mask = batch["encoder_mask"].to(device) # (b, 1, 1, seq_len)

            # check that the batch size is 1
            assert encoder_input.size(
                0) == 1, "Batch size must be 1 for validation"

            model_out = greedy_decode(model, encoder_input, encoder_mask, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, max_len, device)

            source_text = batch["src_text"][0]
            target_text = batch["tgt_text"][0]
            model_out_text = tokenizer_tgt.decode(model_out.detach().cpu().numpy())

            source_texts.append(source_text)
            expected.append(target_text)
            predicted.append(model_out_text)
            
            # Print the source, target and model output
            print_msg('-'*console_width)
            print_msg(f"{f'SOURCE: ':>12}{source_text}")
            print_msg(f"{f'TARGET: ':>12}{target_text}")
            print_msg(f"{f'PREDICTED: ':>12}{model_out_text}")

            if count == num_examples:
                print_msg('-'*console_width)
                break
    
    
    # Evaluate the character error rate
    # Compute the char error rate 
    metric = torchmetrics.CharErrorRate()
    cer = metric(predicted, expected)
    wandb.log({'validation/cer': cer, 'global_step': global_step})

    # Compute the word error rate
    metric = torchmetrics.WordErrorRate()
    wer = metric(predicted, expected)
    wandb.log({'validation/wer': wer, 'global_step': global_step})

    # Compute the BLEU metric
    metric = torchmetrics.BLEUScore()
    bleu = metric(predicted, expected)
    wandb.log({'validation/BLEU': bleu, 'global_step': global_step})

def get_all_sentences(ds, lang):
    for item in ds:
        yield item['translation'][lang]

def get_or_build_tokenizer(config, ds, lang):
    tokenizer_path = Path(config['tokenizer_file'].format(lang))
    if not Path.exists(tokenizer_path):
        # Most code taken from: https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/quicktour
        tokenizer = Tokenizer(WordLevel(unk_token="[UNK]"))
        tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()
        trainer = WordLevelTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[PAD]", "[SOS]", "[EOS]"], min_frequency=2)
        tokenizer.train_from_iterator(get_all_sentences(ds, lang), trainer=trainer)
        tokenizer.save(str(tokenizer_path))
    else:
        tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file(str(tokenizer_path))
    return tokenizer

def get_ds(config):
    # It only has the train split, so we divide it overselves
    ds_raw = load_dataset('opus_books', f"{config['lang_src']}-{config['lang_tgt']}", split='train')

    # Build tokenizers
    tokenizer_src = get_or_build_tokenizer(config, ds_raw, config['lang_src'])
    tokenizer_tgt = get_or_build_tokenizer(config, ds_raw, config['lang_tgt'])

    # Keep 90% for training, 10% for validation
    train_ds_size = int(0.9 * len(ds_raw))
    val_ds_size = len(ds_raw) - train_ds_size
    train_ds_raw, val_ds_raw = random_split(ds_raw, [train_ds_size, val_ds_size])

    train_ds = BilingualDataset(train_ds_raw, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, config['lang_src'], config['lang_tgt'], config['seq_len'])
    val_ds = BilingualDataset(val_ds_raw, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, config['lang_src'], config['lang_tgt'], config['seq_len'])

    # Find the maximum length of each sentence in the source and target sentence
    max_len_src = 0
    max_len_tgt = 0

    for item in ds_raw:
        src_ids = tokenizer_src.encode(item['translation'][config['lang_src']]).ids
        tgt_ids = tokenizer_tgt.encode(item['translation'][config['lang_tgt']]).ids
        max_len_src = max(max_len_src, len(src_ids))
        max_len_tgt = max(max_len_tgt, len(tgt_ids))

    print(f'Max length of source sentence: {max_len_src}')
    print(f'Max length of target sentence: {max_len_tgt}')
    

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=config['batch_size'], shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

    return train_dataloader, val_dataloader, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt

def get_model(config, vocab_src_len, vocab_tgt_len):
    model = build_transformer(vocab_src_len, vocab_tgt_len, config["seq_len"], config['seq_len'], d_model=config['d_model'])
    return model

def train_model(config):
    # Define the device
    # device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else  "cpu")

    # Define the device
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "mps" if torch.has_mps or torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"
    print("Using device:", device)

    # if device == 'cuda':
    # # CUDA device information
    #     cuda_device = torch.cuda.current_device()
    #     print(f"Device name: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(cuda_device)}")
    #     print(f"Device memory: {torch.cuda.get_device_properties(cuda_device).total_memory / 1024 ** 3} GB")
    # elif device == 'mps':
    #     # MPS device information
    #     print("Device name: <MPS>")  # Adjust this based on specific MPS details if available
    # else:
    # # CPU device information or fallback message
    #     print("NOTE: If you have a GPU, consider using it for training.")
    #     print("      On a Windows machine with NVidia GPU, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMSjDTU8Zlc")
    #     print("      On a Mac machine, run: pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio torchtext --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu")

    # Set device for torch tensors
    device = torch.device(device)

    # Make sure the weights folder exists
    Path(config['model_folder']).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    train_dataloader, val_dataloader, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt = get_ds(config)
    model = get_model(config, tokenizer_src.get_vocab_size(), tokenizer_tgt.get_vocab_size()).to(device)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=config['lr'], eps=1e-9)

    # If the user specified a model to preload before training, load it
    initial_epoch = 0
    global_step = 0
    if config['preload']:
        model_filename = get_weights_file_path(config, config['preload'])
        print(f'Preloading model {model_filename}')
        state = torch.load(model_filename)
        model.load_state_dict(state['model_state_dict'])
        initial_epoch = state['epoch'] + 1
        optimizer.load_state_dict(state['optimizer_state_dict'])
        global_step = state['global_step']
        del state

    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=tokenizer_src.token_to_id('[PAD]'), label_smoothing=0.1).to(device)

    # define our custom x axis metric
    wandb.define_metric("global_step")
    # define which metrics will be plotted against it
    wandb.define_metric("validation/*", step_metric="global_step")
    wandb.define_metric("train/*", step_metric="global_step")

    for epoch in range(initial_epoch, config['num_epochs']):
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        model.train()
        batch_iterator = tqdm(train_dataloader, desc=f"Processing Epoch {epoch:02d}")
        for batch in batch_iterator:

            encoder_input = batch['encoder_input'].to(device) # (b, seq_len)
            decoder_input = batch['decoder_input'].to(device) # (B, seq_len)
            encoder_mask = batch['encoder_mask'].to(device) # (B, 1, 1, seq_len)
            decoder_mask = batch['decoder_mask'].to(device) # (B, 1, seq_len, seq_len)

            # Run the tensors through the encoder, decoder and the projection layer
            encoder_output = model.encode(encoder_input, encoder_mask) # (B, seq_len, d_model)
            decoder_output = model.decode(encoder_output, encoder_mask, decoder_input, decoder_mask) # (B, seq_len, d_model)
            proj_output = model.project(decoder_output) # (B, seq_len, vocab_size)

            # Compare the output with the label
            label = batch['label'].to(device) # (B, seq_len)

            # Compute the loss using a simple cross entropy
            loss = loss_fn(proj_output.view(-1, tokenizer_tgt.get_vocab_size()), label.view(-1))
            batch_iterator.set_postfix({"loss": f"{loss.item():6.3f}"})

            # Log the loss
            wandb.log({'train/loss': loss.item(), 'global_step': global_step})

            # Backpropagate the loss
            loss.backward()

            # Update the weights
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)

            global_step += 1

        # Run validation at the end of every epoch
        run_validation(model, val_dataloader, tokenizer_src, tokenizer_tgt, config['seq_len'], device, lambda msg: batch_iterator.write(msg), global_step)

        # Save the model at the end of every epoch
        model_filename = get_weights_file_path(config, f"{epoch:02d}")
        torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'global_step': global_step
        }, model_filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    config = get_config()
    config['num_epochs'] = 30
    config['preload'] = None

    wandb.init(
        # set the wandb project where this run will be logged
        project="pytorch-transformer",
        
        # track hyperparameters and run metadata
        config=config
    )
    
    train_model(config)


